# Using $lte and $gte with find command does not yield any error or result

Tags: mongodb

My collection name: **stu**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a1f7a6f432505f3a6b287b"), "name" : "user1", "mark1" : "100", "mark2" : "200" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a1fd3cf432505f3a6b287c"), "name" : "user2", "mark1" : "89", "mark2" : "70" }
```

Query I wrote

```
> db.stu.find({"mark1":{$gt:50}}).pretty()
```

What is the problem here? `gt,lt gte,lte` are also not working.

Comment: I think the marks stored in collection has string datatype.

Comment: You would be better off converting your data to the right data type than ever using anything like JS evaluation for find

Answer (score 0):

It's because the values for `mark1` fields are not numerical and you are using integers in your find query for comparison. To fix this, convert your `mark1` fields from string to numeric values then your comparison queries will work.

Answer (score 0):

`mark1` is a string. `$gt` works with numbers only. Javascript comparison should work though:

```
db.stu.find("this.mark1 > 50").pretty()
```